# embedded C #define

Tags: c, arm, embedded, cmsis

In embedded C, I ran into the following (and many more similar) example:

```
#define GPIOA_AHB         ((GPIOA_AHB_Type          *) GPIOA_AHB_BASE)
```

GPIOA_AHB_BASE is an address, and it is defined previously. What does this code precisely do? I know defines are directive for the preprocessor, so that it replaces all instances with the value given in the define. For example,

```
 #define GPIOA_AHB   GPIOA_AHB_BASE
```

would replace GPIOA_AHB with whatever value GPIOA_AHB_BASE has been defined. I don't get though what's happening in the first case...

Comment: You might get the preprocessed form of your source code (e.g. using something like `gcc -C -E yoursource.c > yoursource.i`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full details can't be stated from the information in the question, but:

1. If the source code contains `GPIOA_AHB` as an identifier, it will be replaced by `((GPIOA_AHB_Type *)GPIOA_AHB_BASE)` initially.
2. What happens next depends on whether either `GPIOA_AHB_Type` or `GPIOA_AHB_BASE` is itself a macro.
3. If there is a `#define GPIOA_AHB_BASE 0x10000` say, then that value is inserted in the replacement text.  Similarly, if there is a `#define GPIOA_AHB_Type uint8_t`, then the value is inserted in the replacement text, leading to code containing:

   ```
   ((uint8_t *)0x10000)
   ```
4. That value can be dereferenced and a memory read will occur that actually references the GPIO bus and device.

Comment: Thanks! Up to point 3. I see now what's happening. The part ((uint8_t *)0x10000) is still blury... Would that return the value stored at the address 0x10000 casted to uint8_t?

Comment: In the hypothetical expansion I showed, you would have an expression like: `uint8_t b = *GPIOA_AHB;` to read a byte from that address, or `*GPIOA_AHB = 0x83;` to write a byte to that address.  The general concept (an address you can read from or write to) is accurate; the detailed mechanics depend on the definitions. If the `GPIOA_AHB_Type` is a structure instead of a simple type, then you can use `GPIOA_AHB->member` to access a member of the structure. The main point is that it converts a memory address dictated by hardware into something a C program can use. It is unportable, but effective.

Comment: More commonly these kind of macros are written as: `#define GPIOA_AHB (*(volatile uint8_t*) GPIOA_AHB_BASE)`. That way you don't have to dereference but treat the register as any other variable. Also, the type needs to be volatile, since it is a hardware memory location.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of `GPIOA_AHB` I can conclude that it is used to reference registers of a `GPIO/AHB` device.

The notation to access these registers would be `GPIOA_AHB->some_register` .

If you would have defined `GPIOA_AHB` as you describe in the second case, it would just be a plain number. You would not be able to use it to reference registers without first casting it to the structure that describes the registers offsets within that device (`GPIOA_AHB_Type`) or manually adding the offsets of each register within that device register space.